# Edit and save input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a to-do list. What I want is, when I click on task, he is going to input after that I have "Save" button, but I don't know how next, how to put back same saved task in list?

Also, I know I need to add ID of `li`, but how to add to every new `li` ID?

```js
// add button and remove
$(function() {
  var listState = 'add';
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    if (listState === 'add') {
      let list = $('.input').val();
      if (list !== '') {
        $('ul').append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></span>" + list + "</li>");
        $('.input').val('');
        $('ul').on('click', 'span', function() {
          $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.input').val('');
          });
        });
        return false;
      }
    } else if (listState === 'edit') {

    };
  });
  //save button
  $(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
    listState = 'edit';
    $('.input').val($(this).text());
    $('.add').html('Save')
  });
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    $('.add').html('Add');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do List - Jquery</h1>
  <p><em>Click and delete</em></p>
  <form class="form">
    <label>Enter a new task:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your task">
    <button class="add">Add</button><button type="reset" class="reset">Clear</button>
    <ul>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: why you say "i need to put ID on li"?

Comment: My idea is to put ID on li and use data(), or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` of `li` which is clicked and save it in some variable and when you click on `save` button use this `index` to add value to required `li` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// add button and remove
$(function() {
  var listState = 'add';
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    if (listState === 'add') {
      let list = $('.input').val();
      if (list !== '') {
        $('ul').append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash-o'> </i></span>" + list + "</li>");
        $('.input').val('');
        $('ul').on('click', 'span', function() {
          $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.input').val('');
          });
        });
        return false;
      }
    } else if (listState === 'edit') {

    };
  });
  var indexs;
  //save button
  $(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
    listState = 'edit';
    indexs = $(this).index() //get index of li clicked
    $('.input').val($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim());
    $('.add').html('Save')
  });
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    listState = 'add';
    if ($(this).text() == "Save") {
      //use index to add htmls 
      $("li:eq(" + indexs + ")").html("<span><i class='fa fa-trash-o'> </i></span>" + $('.input').val())
      $('.add').html('Add');
      $('.input').val('')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">)
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do List - Jquery</h1>
  <p><em>Click and delete</em></p>
  <form class="form">
    <label>Enter a new task:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your task">
    <button class="add" type="button">Add</button><button type="reset" class="reset">Clear</button>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </form>

</div>
```

Other way is using *data attribute* .So, whenever your `li` is clicked set flag value as true and then use this data attribute to save value to required `li`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// add button and remove
$(function() {
  var listState = 'add';
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    if (listState === 'add') {
      let list = $('.input').val();
      if (list !== '') {
        $('ul').append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash-o'> </i></span>" + list + "</li>");
        $('.input').val('');
        $('ul').on('click', 'span', function() {
          $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.input').val('');
          });
        });
        return false;
      }
    } else if (listState === 'edit') {

    };
  });
  //save button
  $(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
    listState = 'edit';
    $('.input').val($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim());
    $(this).attr("data-edit", true); //add data attribute true
    $("li").not($(this)).attr("data-edit", false); //other li to false
    $('.add').html('Save')
  });
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    listState = 'add';
    if ($(this).text() == "Save") {
      $("[data-edit=true]").html("<span><i class='fa fa-trash-o'> </i></span>" + $('.input').val()) //use same to add new content
      $('.add').html('Add');
      $('.input').val('')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">)
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do List - Jquery</h1>
  <p><em>Click and delete</em></p>
  <form class="form">
    <label>Enter a new task:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your task">
    <button class="add" type="button">Add</button><button type="reset" class="reset">Clear</button>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </form>

</div>
```